# Как отправить уведомление на устройство Android с сервера без GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)?

Tags: php, android

Я долго искала и к сожалению долго нахожу один и тот же ответ - использование `GCM`. Мне это не выгодно, я хочу со своего сервера отправлять клиенту на Android уведомление, но без использования сторонних сервисов, если возможно то в идеале написать свой подобный сервис. На android можно получить свой `id`, который можно сохранить в базе на сервере. Вот пример как получить `id`.

```
String android_id = Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Secure.AndroidId);
```

Он уникальный для каждого телефона, я думаю из него можно сформировать токен подобный "GCM Токену",добавив туда какую-то ссылку или сгенерированный ключ, но я не могу найти решений как с сервера отправлять уведомления. Сервер к слову написан на PHP. Со стороны клиента проблем думаю не возникнет, я могу написать класс `Receiver`, который будет слушать события. На данный момент я пользуюсь службой заднего плана(`StartForegroundService`), которая слушает сокет все время и когда происходит событие в нем, то она его обрабатывает. Но служба тратит много батареи и + ко всему, она постоянно весит в шторке телефона.

Comment: Я понимаю, что gcm это некая прослойка между сервером и клиентом , но мне нужно избавится от нее или заменить чем то.

Comment: А других вариантов нет - для пушей нужен постоянно открытый сокет. Поэтому самый оптимальный вариант ловить все пуши одним сервисом на все приложения - это и реализует FCM/GCM. Если вас устроит периодический опрос, то посмотрите в сторону `WorkManager`

Comment: @woesss, Я рассматривала варианта WorkManager - но это не подходит. Мне нужна регулярная связь с с сервом, естественно при условии, что есть интернет

Comment: Тут два стула - или решение от корпорации зла (FCM) или ваше решение с уведомлением и сокет соединением. Других вариантов нет.